# time.ctime(secs) function in Python gives a different date as using DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, python, datetime, time

I have a number represents seconds from epoch time, 1490976000.
In python 3.5, call time.ctime(1490976000), I got 'Fri Mar 31 09:00:00 2017',

however in .NET C#, when I using following code,

```
DateTime initDT = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(initDT.AddSeconds(1490976000).ToString());
```

I got '3/31/2017 4:00:00 PM', as you can see, the hour is different with in python, anyone knows why?

Comment: What timezone are you in? Could it be local vs UTC?

Comment: the doc of time.ctime function says "Convert a time expressed in seconds since the epoch to a string representing local time", so I assume in python it uses local time. I don't know what the default timezone C# uses, so I also tried DateTime initDT = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,DateTimeKind.Local); I got the same result.

Comment: The csharp [datetime constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130(v=vs.110).aspx) says: _For applications in which portability of date and time data or a limited degree of time zone awareness is important, you can use the corresponding DateTimeOffset constructor._ ....meaning csharp tends to keep its documentation as obscure as possible... but yeah, its in UTC.

Comment: @tdelaney The default is unspecified, actually. Running these three locally: `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)` `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime()` `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).ToUniversalTime()` the result is `1/01/1970 12:00:00 AM` `1/01/1970 11:00:00 AM` `31/12/1969 1:00:00 PM`. Since there's no kind, I believe converting to local assumes you start from UTC, and converting to UTC assumes you start from local, if no current kind is provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not fluent in python, however reading the documentation, it states:

> time.ctime([secs])
>
> Convert a time expressed in seconds since the epoch to a string ***representing local time***. If secs is not provided or None, the current time as returned by time() is used. ctime(secs) is equivalent to asctime(***localtime(secs)***). Locale information is not used by ctime().

So with that information taken into account, we need to do the same in .NET:

```
DateTime initDT = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime();
var result = initDT.AddSeconds(1490976000);
```

Comment: interesting, i wonder why DateTime initDT = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local) gives a different result.

Comment: @pluto If your timezone is +10, then your version means '1970 00AM +10:00', while mine represents '1970 00AM +0' -> '1970 10AM +10:00'

Answer (score 2):

This Python code matches what you got from C#:

```
>>> from datetime import *
>>> datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=1490976000)
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 16, 0)
```

That's the correct answer for UTC.  But `ctime()` converts from UTC to your *local* time zone.

If you want UTC, and don't want to use Python's `datetime`, use Python's `time.gmtime()` instead:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.gmtime(1490976000)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=31,
                 tm_hour=16, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0,
                 tm_wday=4, tm_yday=90, tm_isdst=0)
>>> time.asctime(_)
'Fri Mar 31 16:00:00 2017'
```